# Unintended caption coloring

Tags: color, page-breaking

I do have a command, which prints out part of the text in different color.

```
\newcommand{\indexit}[1]{\index{#1}{\sffamily\color{NavyBlue}#1}}
```

It works fine, but if pagination breaks `#1`, and a program listing follows on the new page,
then the caption of the listing takes the color NavyBlue. I do use the definition

```
{\begin{program}[h!btp] }
 \caption{#3}
 \lstinputlisting[label=#4, name=#4] {#2}
....
```

Without making an MWE (it would be tricky to provoke such a situation, a format description submitted, etc.), do you have any idea, what could be the problem?

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\indexit}[1]{\index{#1}{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\sffamily #1}}}` i.e., use `\textcolor` instead of `\color`.

Comment: Either Harish's proposition or `\newcommand{\indexit}[1]{\index{#1}{\sffamily{\color{NavyBlue}#1}}}`, i.e. an additional group around `\color`, otherwise the color leaks into text until the outer group is closed, but `\textcolor` is definitely better

Comment: @HarishKumar this is the answer.

Comment: I removed some tags since the problem is not connected to `captions` or `listings`, it's a common error when `\color` command is used and has nothing to do with `\caption` or `\index` itself.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I do have the experience only when the colored part is broken in favor of listing caption. No figure, etc. has similar effect

Answer (score 1):

`\color{NavyBlue}#1` needs to be contained inside a group for its effect to be local. Hence you need to enclose it inside a pair of braces like `{\color{NavyBlue}#1}`.

```
\newcommand{\indexit}[1]{\index{#1}{\sffamily{\color{NavyBlue}#1}}}
```

However, this will give you surprises some times by behaving in an odd manner. The safest way is to use `\textcolor` command in

```
\newcommand{\indexit}[1]{\index{#1}{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\sffamily #1}}}
```

where there won't be any surprises.